# can't inject DOM element with node.insertBefore() approach

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a list of items sorted in the alphabetic way. The idea was is to inject a corresponding letter from `alphabetArr` array after `<li>` with an id from `DOMElementsArr` array. What am I doing wrong?

No errors in the console but it doesn't work.

Arrays:

```
let alphabetArr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p",
    "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

let DOMElementsArr = ['8MM', ... ,'Daddy_Day_Care']
```

Here is my approach:

```
//create function that injects new element
function insertAfter(el, referenceNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(el, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

//function that loops through both arrays
function injectAllAlphabetLetters(){

  //Create new element
  let newEl = document.createElement('li');
  newEl.className = 'titles alphabet';

  for (let i = 0; i < alphabetArr.length; i++){
  console.log(alphabetArr[i]);
  newEl.innerHTML = alphabetArr[i][0];
  }

  let ref; 

  for (let j = 0; j < DOMElementsArr.length; j++){
    console.log(DOMElementsArr[j]);
    ref = document.getElementById(DOMElementsArr[j]);
  }

  insertAfter(newEl, ref);
}

injectAllAlphabetLetters();
```

Comment: you are calling `insertAfter` only once...

Comment: combine both loops and call `insertAfter` within loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code you are just creating a single element, then iterating and updating its content, then getting element on next loop and finally you are calling the `insertAfter` function only once with last values.

To make it works, you have to combine both the loop and then move the insertion code to the loop.

```
//create function that injects new element
function insertAfter(el, referenceNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(el, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

//function that loops through both arrays
function injectAllAlphabetLetters() {
  // iterate until last element of minimum length array(to avoid problem in case array length are different)
  for (let i = 0; i < alphabetArr.length && i < DOMElementsArr.length; i++) {    
    //Create new element and set properties
    let newEl = document.createElement('li');
    newEl.className = 'titles alphabet';    
    newEl.innerHTML = alphabetArr[i][0];

    // get the element based on id
    let ref = document.getElementById(DOMElementsArr[i]);    
    // call function to insert
    insertAfter(newEl, ref);
  }

}

injectAllAlphabetLetters();
```